# Record Auto generated email and password in jmeter in a csv to use for another test

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm doing a jmeter test for a signup page and a separate test for a login page where in the sign up page test I auto generate the email and password and use the same data for the login page test. So I want to know whether there's a way where I can log the email and password in a csv file that is auto generated in jmeter signup test so I can use the same file details for the login process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is one [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) which you would place after you generate login credentials. In it, you could use something like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

File myFile = new File("pathToMyFile"); // e.g. /home/myName/Desktop/CSV.csv

try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile,
        true)) {
    fileOutputStream.write(String.format("%s,%s\n", vars.get("EMAIL"),
            vars.get("PASSWORD")));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I used a regular extractor to get the email and password value and passed it into the beanshell with the following code and wrote it to a file.

```html
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

email = vars.get("email1");
password = vars.get("password");

log.info(email);  // if you want to log something to jmeter.log file

// Pass true if you want to append to existing file
// If you want to overwrite, then don't pass the second argument
f = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/njs.s/Desktop/Njs/Jmeter/MarketJmeterScripts/csvfile.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(email + "," + password);
f.close();
```